# What neural mechanism is responsible for our identification with a group?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, social-psychology, neural-network, rationality, reward

Why do we need to identify ourselves with a group? Is there naturally a hormone/neurotransmiter reward? Or is it based on more complex mechanisms like finding the "deeper" meanings of our actions?